# systemd type=forking service with multiple invocations

Tags: systemd

Is it possible to write a systemd service like:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=forksomething
```

and allow a second `systemctl --user start forksomething.service` while the first invocation is still running?

I have considered making it `forksomething@.service`, and starting as `"forksomething@$(date +'%s').service"`, I'm just hoping for something less hacky. (Edit: actually, that would be even worse, since it would have to create the symlink and daemon-reload too.)

Answer (score 1):

Once you create your `forksomething@.service` and run `systemctl daemon-reload` once, `systemd` will be ready to start any number of `forksomething@anything.service` services without further daemon-reloads.

In fact, your `forksomething@.service` is actually a *service template*. You can use the part after the `@` in the instance name as a parameter in your template. For example, if you define your service like this:

```
[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/forksomething "%i"
```

and then run:

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl start forksomething@1.service
systemctl start forksomething@2.service
systemctl start forksomething@3.service
```

then systemd will run commands `/usr/local/sbin/forksomething 1`, `/usr/local/sbin/forksomething 2` and `/usr/local/sbin/forksomething 3` for you.

If you wanted the first two instances to persistently start at every boot from this point on, you would only need to say `systemctl enable forksomething@1.service` and `systemctl enable forksomething@2.service`. These commands would automatically create the appropriate symlinks to the appropriate `/etc/systemd/system/<whatever>.target.wants/` directory.

An instance of a service template can be called into existence just by attempting to start it; symlinks are only needed if you want it to be persistently associated with some target unit (usually `default.target` or `multi-user.target` if you want something started at boot, although you can specify `Before=some.target` in your service template if you want the instances associated with some other target).

Comment: Oh thanks, so my proposed 'hacky' solution would work after all - I didn't realise instances of templated services didn't *have* to be enabled. That really is still a hack though - what I really want is to declare `forksomething.service` inactive once it's forked (but leave the forked process running) so that it can be run again - is it possible? (I have no set number to run, nor anything meaningful to name them or to do with the `%i`s.)

Comment: As long as the first `forksomething` process or any of its children (of Nth generation) exist, the control group `systemd` created for it will exist and be non-empty. This sounds like an XY problem - perhaps you should instead create a script that will run an instance of your `forksomething` in the background whenever it receives a signal or other suitable request, and run *that script* as a service?

Comment: I did consider that, but then I'd be `systemctl reload`ing in order to send the signal? Not sure it's much better. Thanks again.